# Return a Struct defined in a separate header file: unknown type name

Tags: c++, struct, tizen

Hello I'm doing a project in C++ (Tizen Platform to be specific) which I'm pretty new to. How can I implement a function that returns a struct, which is defined in a separate header file? I thought you would go about and do like the code below.

FileName.h

```
1.  typedef struct StructName {
2.      int hello;
3.      int there;
4.      int friend;
5.      Foo(int num) : hello(99), there(25) {
6.          friend = num;
7.      }
8.  } StructName;
9.
10. virtual StructName FunctionName(void);
```

The forward decleration of the function on line 10's return type StructName seems to be referencing correctly to the struct in the FileName.h file.

FileName.cpp

```
1.  #include FileName.h
2.
3.  StructName FunctionName(void) {
4.      int n = 5;
5.      StructName s(n);
6.      return s;
7.  }
```

The error I'm receiving is "unknown type name 'StructName'" on **line 3 in FileName.cpp**.
However, StructName in FileName.cpp on **line 5 seems to referencing correctly** to the struct in the header file.

I've been trying to read up on similar problems here on Stack Overflow but none of the answers solved my problem.

For example,
If I add the keyword 'struct' in front of the functions' return type (in both of the files) and the returning variable s in the function in FileName.cpp I get another error saying:

- out-of-line definition of 'FileName::FunctionName' differs from the declaration in the return type

and

- no viable conversion from 'struct StructName' (aka 'FileName::StructName') to 'struct StructName' (aka 'StructName')

Comment: As a side note, you should not name a variable `friend` as that is a C++ keyword.

Comment: Please show your class contexts.  The `virtual` keyword and `FileName::FunctionName` in an error message don't fit with your global-looking definitions.

Comment: @Cyber Thank you for pointing that out. I didn't know.
Anyways, my friend helped med solve the problem and I'll post the solution below.

Comment: @aschelper This might be Tizen related because it was indeed the error message I did receive. There was no difference to the error message if I removed the virtual keyword from the declaration of the function in FileName.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me *might* be Tizen related, since I haven't seen any post with this solution before on Stack Overflow (and Tizen is not that common). If anyone could confirm or deny that would be great.

Anyways, the solution that my friend came up with was to add 'FileName::' in front of the return type of the function specified in FileName.cpp (not necessary in FileName.h) The complete solution is posted below with highlights of what fixed the problem (**line 3 in FileName.cpp**).

FileName.h

```
1.  typedef struct StructName {
2.      int hello;
3.      int there;
4.      int friend;
5.      Foo(int num) : hello(99), there(25) {
6.          friend = num;
7.      }
8.  } StructName;
9.
10. virtual StructName FunctionName(void);
```

FileName.cpp

```
1.  #include FileName.h
2.
3.  FileName::StructName FunctionName(void) { // <- Adding 'FileName::' infront of
4.      int n = 5;                            // the return type fixed the problem
5.      StructName s(n);
6.      return s;
7.  }
```